# HelloSign iframe display in magento2 custom page

Tags: magento2, api, iframe

I need to integrate the HelloSign API in my phtml file. I followed this way but iframe is not coming.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.hellosign.com/public/js/hellosign-embedded.LATEST.min.js"></script>

<!-- Script code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    HelloSign.init("0005fc6cf93ce7ce6116778265107d5a");
HelloSign.open({
    url: "https://app.hellosign.com/editor/embeddedSign?signature_id=78caf2a1d01cd39cea2bc1cbb340dac3&token=b6b8e7deaf8f0b95c029dca049356d4a2cf9710a",
    uxVersion: 2,
    allowCancel: true,
    debug: true,
    skipDomainVerification: true,
    height: 640
});
</script>
```

Console error:

```
{url: "https://app.hellosign.com/editor/embeddedSign?sign…c3&token=b6b8e7deaf8f0b95c029dca049356d4a2cf9710a", uxVersion: 2, allowCancel: true, debug: true, skipDomainVerification: true, …}
allowCancel:true
debug:true
height:640
skipDomainVerification:true
url:"https://app.hellosign.com/editor/embeddedSign?signature_id=78caf2a1d01cd39cea2bc1cbb340dac3&token=b6b8e7deaf8f0b95c029dca049356d4a2cf9710a"
uxVersion:2
__proto__:Object
```

Can anyone help me.

Comment: check browser console logs

Comment: {url: "https://app.hellosign.com/editor/embeddedSign?sign…c3&token=b6b8e7deaf8f0b95c029dca049356d4a2cf9710a", uxVersion: 2, allowCancel: true, debug: true, skipDomainVerification: true, …}
allowCancel
:
true
debug
:
true
height
:
640
skipDomainVerification
:
true
url
:
"https://app.hellosign.com/editor/embeddedSign?signature_id=78caf2a1d01cd39cea2bc1cbb340dac3&token=b6b8e7deaf8f0b95c029dca049356d4a2cf9710a"
uxVersion
:
2
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: Please edit it your comment or your question, I mean paste that console log in proper way, so I can understand.

Comment: Updated in the question can you check now

Comment: This is not the error, this is information/log for developers.

find this `hsEmbeddedOverlay` in inspect element.

Comment: hsEmbeddedOverlay I found in sources. then how to get the data in the iframe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77926/discussion-between-venkata-prasad-and-kunj).

Comment: do you got solution?

Comment: no kunj. Still displayed the empty page.

Comment: let us talk in chat